# Is the free version of Portal identical to the paid version?

Tags: steam, portal

Portal is [currently free](http://www.learnwithportals.com/) (through Sept 20th, 2011) to download with Steam. Are there any restrictions on the free version, or is it completely identical to the paid version? For example, does this count as owning a Source game for the purposes of mods that require you to have a game with the Source engine installed?

Comment: How do you find out about when they have free offers for games?  I'd jump on just about any offer they have if I knew when it would happen, most of the time I don't.

Comment: @Jeff in this case, I noticed when Jeff Atwood retweeted [something about it](https://twitter.com/#!/siracusa/status/114827428693676034). In the past I've heard about offers through various tech blogs, twitter, etc. I don't know of any official source from Valve that lists current offers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The last time Valve made Portal free, it was identical in every way save one: You couldn't get the Source SDK with the free version, which you need to play mods.

However, Valve used to give you the SDK when you purchased Team Fortress 2, which is now free to play, so that may have changed.

Comment: This is good info. If somebody can provide confirmation that these same things apply to the current offer, that would be helpful.

Comment: @nhinkle http://cl.ly/GeAU/Screenshot%202012-05-14%20at%207.30.33%20pm.png

Answer (score 0):

Portal is absolutely free—it's the same version, it applies to the current offer. Again, you will not get the SDK. Enjoy your free game! If you have the sequel, it is a big...demake, GLaDOS' voice has no expression, TOO robotic.

> You know, Caroline and stuff..

Enjoy.

Comment: The markup for spoilers is `>!` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Do you have any reference for "it's the same version and applies to the current offer"? If you could provide that, I'd appreciate it; otherwise, you're just repeating what was said above.

Comment: @nhinkle I e-mailed Valve personally. Their Steamworks staff. [Their reply.](http://cl.ly/GeAU/Screenshot%202012-05-14%20at%207.30.33%20pm.png) This is for TF2 mostly, but I also later found out it applies to Portal.